# On click remove hover style until next time element is hovered

Tags: css, vue.js, hover, quasar-framework

There's a button that changes color when a cursor hovers over it.

Example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xftbqku3/5/

I wish to have an effect that goes like this: 
When the button is clicked, disable `background-color` css rule until the next time it is hovered over.

In other words, when I click the button, I want it to show the button color (red or green) and not the hover color until the next time I hover over it.

Is it possible to to this with just css?

Comment: Pure css? No. But you should be able to do it with a new variable (you can even call it new). And set it to true when button is pressed, on false on mouseout  event and give the hover color efect to a class that is active only if the new variable is false.

Comment: @Berci this is what you had in mind? https://jsfiddle.net/xftbqku3/6/

Comment: Basically yes. I don't really use vueJS (so this why my explanation was probably not the best). But basically that is what I was trying to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment(not enough reputation). But maybe you can try using `<input type=checkbox>` and in css `input:checked`